# как правильно прописать xpath, чтобы кликнуть по кнопке(input)?

Tags: java, python, selenium, xpath

[image: скрин html]

Этот фрагмент кода повторяется очень много раз, разнятся в нем только фамилии людей. Как можно выбрать "child" of "sister" - input и кликнуть по нему. Теги td - сестры, а input - дитя сестры.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.='БАДАНИН']/input").click` - не работает((
у меня есть рабочий вариант кода:`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]//input").click()`, но он не подходит, нужна именно фамилия для точности, а не месторасположение тега, т.к. оно периодически меняется, иначе будет выбран не тот человек.

Comment: ``driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'БАДАНИН')]").click()`` работает?

Comment: пробовала такой вариант, к сожалению не работает((, кликабельный элемент содержится в input

Comment: Можно попробовать делать запрос по условиям для детей, к примеру, `//tr[td[contains(text(), 'БАДАНИН')]]/input`. Т.е. "дай первый `tr`, у которого есть ребенок `td` с текстом `БАДАНИН`, и от этого `tr` дай первого ребенка `input`".

Comment: спасибо за наводку =) немного исправила, заработало

Comment: не знаю по какой причине, но с "contains" не хочет ничего находить

Comment: Ну главное, что заработало же!

Answer (score 1):

Хочу внести ясность в то, какой выход найден, самим вопросителем и почему попытки отдельных комментаторов провалились.

Я понимаю, что вам, как автору вопроса, вероятно лень, или может нет времени на изучение дополнительных источников информации о коде и методах которые вы можете применять. Именно поэтому я и решил объяснить вам, что ВЫ делаете и почему это РАБОТАЕТ. А комментаторам вроде Эникейщик'а рассказать почему ИХ примеры НЕ РАБОТАЮТ.

Давайте начнём с исходных данных, у вас есть предположительно нужный вам, но не работающий xPath вида `//tr[.='БАДАНИН']/input` и не нужный но работающий `//tr[4]//input`. У этих xPath почти всё одинако, но есть одно очень значительно отличие:

```
//                          - два слеша ищут по ВСЕЙ иерархии HTML файла
  tr                        - все элементы tr 
    [.='БАДАНИН']           - имеющие в ВО ВСЕХ текстовых элементах значение БАДАНИН
                 /          - внутри которых будет ДОЧЕРНИЙ элемент __ПЕРВОЙ_ЛИНИИ_ГЛУБИНЫ__
                  input     - типа input

//                          - два слеша ищут по ВСЕЙ иерархии HTML файла
  tr                        - все элементы tr
    [4]                     - идущие 4-ми по порядку
       //                   - внутри которых будет ДОЧЕРНИЙ элемент __ЛЮБОЙ_ГЛУБИНЫ_ЛИНИИ__
                  input     - типа input
```

Первый xPath ищет соседа `td`, но типа `input` и кончено же не находит. А второй xPath ищет `input` среди ВСЕХ потомков и потому находит его внутри `td`.

Переходим к тому xPath который вы указали как ответ, и который мне не нравиться, потому что по характеру составления видно, что вы НЕ ПОНЯЛИ В ЧЁМ ПРОБЛЕМА, из-за того, что пока не понимаете что такое xpath и как он строиться.

```
//tr[td[text()='БАДАНИН']]//input
```

Если опустить текстовое требование в xPath, то получиться:

```
//tr//input
```

Что очень похоже на:

```
//tr[4]//input
```

Что же вы делаете в вашем итоговом xPath (`//tr[td[text()='БАДАНИН']]//input'`). Сначала вы находите элемент `tr` внутри которого есть элемент `td` с текстом `БАДАНИН`, а потом ищите среди найденных `tr` ЛЮБОГО потомка `input`.

Ваш xPath работает. Но гораздо правильней тогда составить xPath такого вида:

```
//tr/td[text()='БАДАНИН']/input
```

или даже сократить до `td`:

```
//td[text()='БАДАНИН']/input
```

Далее. Проблема конструкции `contains(text(),'БАДАНИН')` и комментаторов вроде Эникейщик'а. `contains` принимает на вход две СТРОКОВЫЕ переменные. Именно СТРОКОВЫЕ. И именно поэтому `contains` с вводной переменной в виде `text()` не будет работать НИКОГДА. `text()` - это НЕ СТРОКА, а функция.

Вот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) описана сама функция `contains()`.

А вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655588/7685008), как правильно использовать функцию `text()` при использовании `contains()`.

И ещё полезным будет посмотреть вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/7685008) когда при поиске текста использовать `.`, а когда `text()`

И напоследок, **НЕ ПУБЛИКУЙТЕ КОД В ВИДЕ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ**, делая это вы говорите "**мне НЕ НУЖНА помощь**". Ведь из-за этого, никто не может скопировать код и протестировать вашу ситуацию у себя и быстрее решить проблему, и поэтому многие просто проходят МИМО. Весь код (и HTML в том числе) публикуйте в виде текста!

Удачи вам!

И я не в коем случае не злюсь на вас, или ещё что-то в этом роде. Вы молодец, что опубликовали свой вопрос, что вступили в диалог с другими участниками сообщества, что хотите найти решение проблемы. Но я хочу, что-бы вы, для начала, учились на своих ошибках, исправляли их и становились лучше! А так и до профессионала не далеко))))

Comment: Спасибо, что в своем комментарии оставили много полезных ссылок, и вообще, потратили на меня время!! Я учту ваши замечания. Но предложенный вами код, к сожалению не работает. input является ребенком td, который стоит до td(баданин), а предложенное вами решение будет искать input в td(баданин), а в моем решении, xpath находит tr родителя c td(баданин) и ищет input во всем этом td. Я, абсолютный новичок, скорее всего это не идеальное решение. Но искренне говорю спасибо всем ответчикам, правда очень помогли, навели, подучили!!

Comment: Да вы правы. Из-за моего акцента на правильности xPath и исправлении ошибок других комментаторов, я совсем упустил то, как должен был на самом деле построиться xPath.

Answer (score 0):

`//tr[td[text()='БАДАНИН']]//input` - вот так заработало